# Python module error:Randint

Tags: python, random

```
from random import randint
```

This is the code I've used to import the Random module. When I run the code, it instead imports a file of mine for testing code called **random.py**.
This was leading to all sorts of errors, so I 'permanently' deleted it in the Recycle Bin and all it's shortcuts I could find.Yet it still is there somewhere and it causes errors.My entire program depends on

```
x = randint(1, 100)
if x % 2 == 0:
    b = 'c'
```

The game I'm making depends in randint to randomly create ships and submarines.
I am running Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Python creates a *bytecode cache* for each python module you import; for Python 2 the same name as the original file with the extension `.pyc` is used. It is that file that is imported when you import `random`, even if the source `.py` file was deleted.

Use:

```
import random
print(random.__file__)
```

to  locate the stale `random.pyc` bytecode file and delete it.

In Python 3 these files are normally stored in a subdirectory called `__pycache__` but these are ignored if there is no corresponding `.py` source file. People that want to distribute just the bytecode files (to obfuscate their code in commercial software distributions, for eample) they'll have to use the [`compilall` script with the `-b` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html#cmdoption-compileall-b), something you almost certainly did not do.

Answer (score 1):

There will also be a `random.pyc` file, either in the same folder (for Python 2.x) or a subdirectory called `__pycache__` (for 3.x).

Comment: Files in `__pycache__` are ignored if there is no corresponding `.py` file.

Comment: See [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/): *If the py source file is missing, the pyc file inside \_\_pycache__ will be ignored. This eliminates the problem of accidental stale pyc file imports.*

Comment: Huh. They improved matters even more than I thought :)